# What does #{$$} inside a double quoted string in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, double-quotes

I have a doubt concerning #{$$} inside a double quoted string, in concrete I have this string:

```
"#{command}#{$$}#{(Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i}"
```

If I execute "#{$$}" in console I get an integer number but I would like to read an explanation to this.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$$` is the interpreter's process ID.

Ruby has quite a few global variables you can use, [see here.](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about those variables.

Answer (score 3):

That would be the [global process ID](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html).

If you're asking what the #{...} syntax means, that prints the variable inside the braces. So if it would work like this..

```
command = "print"
puts "cmd: #{command}" #=> cmd: print
```

Comment: Thanks, I did know what the #{ } means, I just though adding $$ to it was some special syntas I was missing.